# How can connect routes in rails 3 using folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3

I'm getting an error **No route matches [GET]** because trying to create folders per certain controllers

Here the app structure:

```
|controller,helper,view|
 |user_management| ------> FOLDER
   |user|          ------> SUBFOLDER  
   |login|         ------> SUBFOLDER    
   |chat|          ------> SUBFOLDER  
 |sale_management| ------> FOLDER  
   |sale|          ------> SUBFOLDER  
   |product|       ------> SUBFOLDER
```

Here controllers:

```
 # UserManagement Controllers
 class UserManagement::UserController < ApplicationController
 class UserManagement::LoginController < ApplicationController
 class UserManagement::ChatController < ApplicationController

 # SaleManagement Controllers
 class SaleManagement::SaleController < ApplicationController
 class SaleManagement::ProductController < ApplicationController
```

Here helpers:

```
 module UserManagement::UserHelper
 module UserManagement::LoginHelper
 module UserManagement::ChatHelper
 module SaleManagement::SaleHelper
 module SaleManagement::ProductHelper
```

Router.rb from rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8

```
map.root :controller => "user_management/user", :action=>"index"
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

I'm doing Routes.rb from rails 3 and ruby 1.9 but got **ROUTES ERROR**

```
root :to => 'user_management/user#index'
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Please somebody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example

```
scope module: 'user_management' do
   scope module: 'user' do
      resources :users
   end
end
```

Then you can access `users` like localhost:3000/users

For more detail Check [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Is not working i'm trying to use localhots/user_management/user/login and i'm getting No route matches [GET]  "/user_management/user/index"

Comment: Thanks +1...taked time for me to finally understand rails 4.